# Проблема с foreach

Tags: php, циклы

Мне нужно перебрать массив таким способом чтобы получать наибольшее значение.
Но у меня проблема если они значение больше 0 то выводит не то что нужно.

```
$array = ["0" => [
"name"=>"lol1",
"count"=>2
],
"1" => [
"name"=>"lol",
"count"=>11
]
];
$pl = 0;
foreach($array as $arr){
if($arr['count']>$pl){
    $pl = $arr;

}
}
    print_r($pl);
```

Comment: $pl = $arr['count'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну, для начала - перемення $pl никогда не покажет наибольшее значение в массиве, т.к. она будет содержать только последнее значение , которое больше 0

Comment: а для не начала?

Comment: чтобы получить наибольшее значение, нужно сначала выбрать все count из всех массивов и сформировать новый массив, после этого можно отсортировать елементы внутри нового массива и взять, например, последний елемент (если сортировать по возрастанию)

Comment: $newArr = []; foreach($array as $arr){ $newArr[] = $arr['count'] }

Comment: спасибо уже сделал